# NSIS Plugin with bad string

Tags: c++, nsis, nsis-plugin

I've tried to develop an `NSIS Plugin` in `C++`.

Here is my method to set informations from NSIS:

```
void __declspec(dllexport) SetCredentials(HWND hWndParent, int string_size, TCHAR *variables, stack_t **stacktop, extra_parameters *extra) {
    EXDLL_INIT();

    server      = getuservariable(INST_0);
    port        = myatou(getuservariable(INST_1));
    database    = getuservariable(INST_2);
    username    = getuservariable(INST_3);
    password    = getuservariable(INST_4);

    MessageBox(hWndParent, server, L"Info", MB_OK); // Here is the problem
    setuservariable(INST_0, server);
}
```

Sample:

```
OutFile "Example.exe"
BrandingText " "

Section
   MySQL::SetCredentials "localhost" 3306 "banananode" "root" ""
   Pop $0
   MessageBox MB_OK "Server: $0" ; Returns the server value...
SectionEnd
```

The Problem is, when i try to print out the `server` variable, chinese characters will be shown, not the correct text:

[image]

When i return the value with `setuservariable(INST_0, server);`, NSIS will be display it correctly:

[image]

Can you tell me, whats wrong?
I've tried to build the resulted `.dll` with `pluginapi-x86-ansi.lib` and `pluginapi-x86-unicode.lib` but the result is the same...

Comment: Do you have `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` preprocessor variables defined in your plugin project? Also, you have to set [Unicode attribute](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter1.html#intro-unicode) in NSIS installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANSI characters interpreted as Unicode (UTF-16LE) [tends to look Chinese](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140930-00/?p=43953).

When you create a Unicode plug-in you need to:

- [Make sure](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040715-00/?p=38433) `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` is defined in your project/.C files.
- Link with pluginapi-x86-unicode.lib
- Add `Unicode True` to your .NSI
- Place the plug-in in \NSIS\x86-unicode

In your case you most likely forgot about `Unicode True`. Returning the value works because you never actually changed the memory of `server`, it is still the same input string.