# NSIS popstring fills only one character

Tags: c++, nsis, nsis-plugin

I've tried to read the parameters from NSIS Call like:

```
MySQL::SetCredentials "localhost" 3306 "banananode" "root" ""
```

On method, i've tried to fetch the first parameter with `popstring` like the sample Code on NSIS:

```
LPTSTR mystringbuffer = (LPTSTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, (3 + string_size + 1) * sizeof(*mystringbuffer));
int test = popstring(mystringbuffer);
MessageBox(hWnd, mystringbuffer, TEXT("plug-in"), MB_OK);
GlobalFree(mystringbuffer);
```

But `popstring` returns only `l` and not `localhost`:

[image]

I had tried to use `getuservariable(INST_0)` for sample, but here, it gives me an empty result.

Can you tell me, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is just the opposite of [the problem you had earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608015/nsis-plugin-with-bad-string). You are still mixing and matching ANSI and Unicode strings/functions. A single letter means you read a Unicode string as a ANSI string. `L"localhost"` (`l\0o\0c\0a\0l\0h\0o\0s\0t\0\0\0`) as a ANSI string is just `"l"` (`l\0`).

Perhaps this would reduce the confusion:

```
void __declspec(dllexport) test(HWND hWndParent, ...)
{
  MessageBox(hWndParent, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOA) < sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO) ? TEXT("Unicode plug-in") : TEXT("ANSI plug-in"), TEXT("I'm a"), 0);
}
```

and

```
Section 
!if "${NSIS_CHAR_SIZE}" > 1
  MessageBox mb_ok "Unicode installer"
!else
  MessageBox mb_ok "ANSI installer"
!endif
myplugin::test
SectionEnd
```